# R shared library not found... enable-R-shlib option

Tags: permissions, r, rstudio

I am working with Ubuntu 16.04 and as my computer doesn't have all the permissions I decided to download a local version of R and to have RStudio use that version...

When my computer finished installing everything, R Studio wouldn't open,and I get this error:

```
R shared library not found (/home/rtg/R/R-3.3.2/lib/libR/so) ...enable-R-shlib option", and when I type "which R" in the terminal I get "/user/bin/R
```

How do I fix this error message and how do I get R and R studio to work using the same local version?

Comment: how did you install `R`? i.e. with `--enable-R-shlib` option ??

Comment: if not,uninstall the current installation and install with the command `sudo apt-get install r-base` which will install it with `-enable-R-shlib` option

Comment: that is how i installed my local version of R.